# Understanding the outer products in density matrices

Tags: mathematics, density-matrix, nielsen-and-chuang

I don't understand a simple property of the outer product when doing density matrices. I am studying nielsen and chuang's book.

At equation 2.197 they do show the density matrix of the state of quantum teleportation before alice performs her measurements.
For 
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}[|00\rangle(\alpha|0\rangle +\beta |1\rangle)+ |01\rangle(\alpha|1\rangle+\beta|0\rangle)+|10\rangle(\alpha|0\rangle -\beta |1\rangle) + |11\rangle(\alpha|1\rangle -\beta|0\rangle)]$$
The density matrix is just:
$$\rho_1= \frac{1}{4}[|00\rangle \langle 00|(\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle)(\alpha^*|0\rangle+\beta^*|1\rangle)+\\
|01\rangle\langle01|(\alpha|1\rangle +\beta |0\rangle)(\alpha^*\langle1| +\beta^*\langle0|)  +\\
|10\rangle\langle10|(\alpha|0\rangle -\beta |1\rangle)(\alpha^*\langle 0|-\beta^*\langle1|) +\\
 |11\rangle\langle11|(\alpha|1\rangle -\beta|0\rangle)(\alpha^*\langle 1| -\beta^*\langle0|)
]$$

But in the example a couple of pages before, they present the density matrix of $|+\rangle$, which is:

$$\rho_2=\frac{1}{2} (|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(\langle0| + \langle 1|) $$
Which it gets "opened up" as
$$\rho_2=\frac{1}{2} (|0\rangle\langle0|+ |0\rangle \langle1| + |1\rangle\langle0| + |1\rangle\langle1|) $$

So basically I don't understand why sometimes the outer product you have the cross terms $|0\rangle \langle1|$, and sometimes you dont: I would have expected to have 16 terms in the density matrix of the teleportation, or just 2 in the example of the maximally mixed state.

Specifically, I expect either $\rho_2$ to be (which I understand is plain wrong):
$$\rho_2 = \frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle\langle0| + |1\rangle\langle1|)$$
or $\rho_1$ to be all the cross product terms:
$$\rho_1= \frac{1}{4}[|00\rangle \langle 00|(\alpha|0\rangle + |01\rangle(\alpha^*|1\rangle+\beta^*|0\rangle)+\\
|01\rangle\langle01|(\alpha|0\rangle +\beta |1\rangle)(\alpha^*\langle0| +\beta^*\langle1|)  +\\
|10\rangle\langle10|(\alpha|0\rangle -\beta |1\rangle)(\alpha^*\langle 0|-\beta^*\langle1|) +\\
 |11\rangle\langle11|(\alpha|1\rangle -\beta|1\rangle)(\alpha^*\langle 1| -\beta^*\langle1|+\\
|00\rangle \langle 01|(..)()..)+\\
|00\rangle \langle 10|(..)()..)+\\
|00\rangle \langle 11|(..)()..)+\\
|01\rangle \langle 00|(..)()..)+\\
|01\rangle \langle 10|(..)()..)+\\
|01\rangle \langle 11|(..)()..)+\\
etc..
)
]$$

Can someone tell me what i don get about distributive property of outer products?

Comment: A state $\rho$ needs only be Hermitian and have unit trace. You can have Hermitian matrices with and without cross terms. Does this answer the question?

Comment: No, sorry. I clarified the question with what I expect to be the density matrix in order to have consistence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, there should be 16 terms. But since they are tracing out Alice's system in the next step only 4 terms are relevant - those that correspond to $|00\rangle \langle 00|$, $|01\rangle \langle 01|$, $|10\rangle \langle 10|$ and $|11\rangle \langle 11|$. Tracing out $|00\rangle \langle 01|\cdot |\phi\rangle\langle\psi|$ will result in 0, because $\text{Tr}(|00\rangle \langle 01|)=\langle 01|00\rangle=0$.

Comment: OOOH thanks that should be written I think! :)